# R Tm package dictionary matching leads to higher frequency than actual words of text

Tags: r, dictionary, nlp, frequency, tm

I have been using the code below to load text as a corpus and using the tm package to clean the text. As a next step I am loading a dictionary and cleaning it as well. Then I am matching the words from the text with the dictionary to calculate a score. However, the matching results in a higher number of matches than actual words in the text (e.g., the competence score is 1500 but the actual number of words in the text is only 1000).

I think it is related to the stemming of the text and the dictionary as the matches are lower when there is no stemming performed.

Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Thank you very much.

**R Code**

**Step 1 Storing data as corpus**

`file.path <- file.path(here("Generated Files", "Data Preparation")) corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(file.path))`

**Step 2 Cleaning data**

```
#Removing special characters
toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "/")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "@")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, toSpace, "\\|") 

#Convert the text to lower case
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
#Remove numbers
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
#Remove english common stopwords
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
#Remove your own stop word
specify your stopwords as a character vector
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("view", "pdf")) 
#Remove punctuations
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
#Eliminate extra white spaces
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
#Text stemming
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
#Unique words
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, unique)
```

**Step 3 DTM**

`dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)`

**Step 4 Load Dictionaries**

```
dic.competence <- read_excel(here("Raw Data", "6. Dictionaries", "Brand.xlsx"))
dic.competence <- tolower(dic.competence$COMPETENCE)
dic.competence <- stemDocument(dic.competence)
dic.competence <- unique(dic.competence)
```

**Step 5 Count frequencies**

```
corpus.terms = colnames(dtm)
competence = match(corpus.terms, dic.competence, nomatch=0)
```

**Step 6 Calculate scores**

```
competence.score = sum(competence) / rowSums(as.matrix(dtm))
competence.score.df = data.frame(scores = competence.score)
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `competence` return when you run that line? I'm not sure how your dictionary is set up, so I can't say for certain what's happening there. I brought in my own random corpus text as the primary text and brought in a separate corpus as the dictionary and your code worked great. The row names of `competence.score.df` were the names of the different txt files in my corpus and the scores were all in a 0-1 range.

```
# this is my 'dictionary' of terms:
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(DirSource("./corpus/corpus3")),
                          control = list(removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                         stopwords = TRUE,
                                         stemming = TRUE,
                                         removePunctuation = TRUE))

# then I used your programming and it worked as I think you were expecting

# notice what I used here for the dictionary    
(competence = match(colnames(dtm), 
                    Terms(tdm)[1:10], # I only used the first 10 in my test of your code
                    nomatch = 0))

(competence.score = sum(competence)/rowSums(as.matrix(dtm)))
(competence.score.df = data.frame(scores = competence.score))
```

Comment: Dear Kat, 
Thank you very much for your suggested solution. My dictionary is set up as normal csv with a column of terms. I tried to run your suggested solution but it still gave me a higher number for competence so there is still a double-matching happening which I can't figure out. But in the beginning I was also not reading in the dictionary as corpus which was a great tip.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the structure of the content in the dictionary csv? Even if it's not the same data, perhaps it would lead me or someone else to give you another idea on how to approach the problem.